# indexOf returns substring index in string

Tags: java, string

Hi i have a string and i want to find index of a particular word but indexOf() method of string returns substring index. For example:

```
String example = "7. Political career He was first elected as an alderman for St.";
int index = example.indexOf("as");
```

But this method returns index of substring "as" in word "was" and not index of word "as".

Comment: Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks so how should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.util.regex.Matcher and java.util.regex.Pattern with a reg ex search to find the specific word.  This link here may help for more information http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Whilst a little more complex it is flexible.

You could include the preceding space in your match string if you absolutely know the data, but I suspect that is not what you are looking for.